# Qt animation - Simultaneously change scale and position using QPropertyAnimation

Tags: python, qt, animation, pyqt, pyside

I'm currently trying to build a slideshow viewer with Qt with the help of the QAnimation framework. I'm having trouble changing the size of a photo while simultaneously moving it as changing the size of a photo in the slideshow while it is moving seems to affect its trajectory.

Specifically, I'm trying to animate a set of photos, making them move continuously from right to left across the horizontal center line of the window while changing in size at the same time. Basically, its sort of a "fish-eye" effect, with the photo becoming larger as it moves towards the center of the window then decrease back to its original size as it moves away.

At any given time, the window will only show 3 photos (plus 1 photo exiting the window on the left). Suppose the 3 photos, ordered from left to right, are labeled P1, P2, P3. Consider one photo, the right-most photo P3. As P3 moves from the right of the window towards the center, its size should gradually increase and hit a maximum size at the center of the window. As it continues to move towards the left and eventually exit the window, its size should decrease back to its original value.

My current implementation works if I'm just moving the photos without resizing them. When simultaneously moving and scaling the image, the photos are no longer moving horizontally across the center of the window. The size of the photos appears to be scaled correctly.

My current implementation relies on the QPropertyAnimation class to perform the animation. I'm writing my program using Python and Qt's PySide bindings, but solutions in C++ or PyQt code are fine. I will just translate them to Python and PySide.

The relevant code are as follows:

```
def animate(self, items):
'''@params: items The photos to animate'''
    logging.debug('Creating %d animation objects', len(items))
    self.animationGroup.clear()
    for i, item in enumerate(items):
        self.animatePosition(item, i, len(items))
        self.animateScale(item, i)
    QTimer.singleShot(START_DELAY, self.animationGroup.start)    

def animatePosition(self, item, index, numItems):
    isLastItem = (index == numItems - 1)
    isFirstItem = (index == 0)

    posAnimation = QPropertyAnimation(item, 'position')
    posAnimation.setDuration(SLIDE_INTERVAL)
    posAnimation.setStartValue(item.pos())
# I've tried changing dh depending on the scale of the current image with limited success.
dh = 0 
    if isLastItem:
        posAnimation.setEndValue(item.pos() - QPointF(slideshow.RIGHT_MARGIN + slideshow.STANDARD_SLIDE_WIDTH, dh))
    elif isFirstItem:
        posAnimation.setEndValue(item.pos() - QPointF(slideshow.LEFT_MARGIN + slideshow.STANDARD_SLIDE_WIDTH, dh))
    else:
        posAnimation.setEndValue(item.pos() - QPointF(slideshow.IMAGE_GAP + slideshow.STANDARD_SLIDE_WIDTH, dh))
    posAnimation.setEasingCurve(QEasingCurve.OutExpo)
    self.animationGroup.addAnimation(posAnimation)

def animateScale(self, item, index):
    if self.animatedView is not None:
        scaleAnimation = QPropertyAnimation(item, 'slideScale')
        scaleAnimation.setDuration(SLIDE_INTERVAL)
        scaleAnimation.setStartValue(item.scale())
        endScale = self.getSlideScale(index - 1)
        scaleAnimation.setEndValue(endScale)
        scaleAnimation.setEasingCurve(QEasingCurve.OutExpo)
        self.animationGroup.addAnimation(scaleAnimation)
```

I know that typically the photo has to be moved back to the origin before applying the scaling transformation, then moved back to the next position on its trajectory. I suspect that the QPropertyAnimation for scaling of the photo is being applied to the translated photo and hence affecting its trajectory, but I could be wrong as I only just started using Qt for the past 1-2 weeks.

Does anyone know how I can make a QPropertyAnimation aware of another animation taking place? Or can anyone suggest a different approach (no necessarily involving QPropertyAnimation) for solving the above problem?

Thanks in advance to any replies.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't use the Qt python bindings, so I don't know if this will help, but in C++ land you want to use [`QAnimationGroup`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qanimationgroup.html) for concurrent animations.

Comment: @sjwarner Hi, sorry I should have provided more code. I'm actually already using a QParallelAnimationGroup object and I've added the QPropertyAnimation objects, 1 for moving and the other for scaling the slide to the QParallelAnimationGroup object. So my guess is that is not the problem. Its either that or my implementation is wrong. In any case I'll check the code again. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are using the QGraphicsView framework (it would have been much easier to understand and debug your problem if you posted a minimal, running example program).

<s>I suggest to use [QGraphicsWidgets](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/qgraphicswidget.html) and animate their ["geometry" property](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/qgraphicswidget.html#geometry-prop) directly</s> (EDIT: I was wrong here, this cannot work).

You need to simultaniously change the size and position without using two QPropertyAnimations.  Most probably the easiest solution will be to *subclass* a QVariantAnimation (or even QVariantAnimation) and implement `updateCurrentValue()` appropriately.  I think I would interpolate a QRectF from which you extract position and size/scale, otherwise you could of course just interpolate a float (which means you would have even more interpolation code to do yourself, but it gets around having to compute the scale from the size).  Consider just marshalling the desired scale into the QRectF’s size (e.g. passing `QSizeF(scale, scale)` to the constructor).  That is a little hackish, because the QRectF is /not/ the desired item geometry anymore, but is otherwise simple and works just great (also with easing curves).  Here is a helpful snippet:

```
class GeometryAnimation(QtCore.QVariantAnimation):
    def __init__(self, item, parent = None):
        QtCore.QVariantAnimation.__init__(self, parent)
        self._item = item

    def updateCurrentValue(self, value):
        self._item.setPos(value.topLeft())
        self._item.setScale(value.width())
```

Why your current code does not work is hard to say and depends on the implementation of the "slideScale" property; if the transformations interact (which I would consider undesired behavior), that would be the cause.

Comment: Hi. Your're correct, I am using the QGraphicsView framework. The slides are QGraphicsPixmapItem and the view is a QGraphicsView. The reason I'm using it instead of widgets is because the qt docs on animation was using it for animating objects and being a newbie at qt I just followed suit. If I were to use QGraphicsWidgets, which class would be appropriate for displaying an image? QLabel? The only class I found when I searched for displaying image was QLabel and QGraphicsPixmapItem but the QLabel is typically used for displaying text, hence I chose the QGraphicsView framework.

Comment: (Sorry for the late answer, was on a journey.)  You can put your QGraphicsPixmapItem into a QGraphicsWidget (as a child), but I have now tried the solution I suggested myself, and found that it does not work like that: The geometry property is simply not the combination of scale and position, but rather a geometry _relative_ to the pos(), and the content will not scale like with the scale() property.

Comment: I have now fixed up my answer above and suggested a working solution. ;-)

Comment: Two more comments:

1. I actually had success with separate pos/scale animations, only not when I used an easing curve (this produces non-matching pos/scale pairs).
2. When implementing the QVariantAnimation subclass, consider just marshalling the desired scale into the QRectF’s size (e.g. passing QSizeF(scale, scale) to the constructor).  That is a little hackish, because the QRectF is /not/ the desired item geometry anymore, but is otherwise simple and works (also with easing curves).